# Java program that's smaller then the the paragraph it prints out (help)

Tags: java

First off, yes this is(was) for school. It was assigned as extra credit and was due Wednesday. However no one was able to solve it and the teacher refused to give us the solution.

The task was to write a java program that would output a paragraph and have the java code smaller then the paragraph itself. (smaller meaning in characters no size) there were a few conditions however. 
1. no input allowed 
2. no importing of files 
3. no downloading from the internet or network

The paragraph that we had to output was this, "I pledge that every program with my name on it shall be written by me (and my co-authors, if any) and that i fully uderstad the program. Every program I submit shall be entirely my own work unless otherwise attributed. I understand that academic dishonesty not only includes copying other people's work, but also abetting or facilitating copying. Code that is similar to any other submission past or present will get no credit whatever the explanation. I understand that the consequence of academic dishonesty is a grade of 'F' for the class. I pledge to devote my efforts to learning Java by writing my own programs. I shall strive to be attentive to detail and write programs understandable by myself and other programmers."

"The total number of characters in the program should be fewer that the total number of characters in the pledge (655 printable, 793 total)."

I have a few ideas but none that I think will work, any ideas?

Comment: What were your ideas? People are more likely to answer questions where you've clearly given it a shot

Comment: At least show a demonstration of effort. Voting to close.

Comment: I have some ideas:  (1) How does "Every program I submit shall be entirely my own work" square with "any ideas?"

Comment: (2) How does "I shall strive to be attentive to detail" square with "i fully uderstad the program"

Comment: `Every program I submit shall be entirely my own work unless otherwise attributed` so if you get the solution from here, then stackoverflow.com will be attributed? ;)

Comment: @emory If it was due the day before yesterday, it won't be submitted anymore, so asking for ideas may be legitimate.

Comment: Hint: There's a bunch of words there that appear more than once.

Comment: @DanielFischer: but shouldn't the original poster first show the fruits of his efforts? That's a valid request regardless of whether this is homework or whether it is past its due date (which we have no way of verifying by the way).

Comment: What if you use a compressed text in the program, and decompress it? You have 96 ASCII characters for the compressed string. Now be creative.

Comment: @Hovercraft Sure. The account of (fruitless) efforts is missing, but that doesn't make the question unethical (only unworthy of answers). Of course you're right, we can't verify the due day is past.

Comment: You could write a program that writes and tests every possible java program of less than 793 characters.  Most won't compile.  Some will compile and produce unacceptable output.  If the assignment is doable at least one will compile and produce the desired output.

Comment: I understand the problem of verifying if the deadline has past or not and why some of you would be hesitant to help. As a first time visitor though this was a bit of a harsh welcome to multiple users in essence calling me a liar and that i was trying to cheat. Thank you to the users who did try and help and didn't assume i was trying to abuse this site.

Comment: @shadowtdt09: no one's calling you anything. We did ask you to show the fruits of your efforts, again not an unreasonable request, but you have yet to do that. Until you do, the post is nothing more than a homework or work dump.

Comment: My only real idea was to import a file (which i asked the teacher about and he revised the challenge to not allow it, and try and replace common words like "program", "I(space)", ".(space)" with string variables but that wouldn't get it down small enough, if it were a longer paragraph it would woke but it is fairly short.

Comment: But that idea seems very logical and everybody would think of it, i am failry confident that the solution is pretty out of the box, like downloading it from the internet (which another student came up with but the teacher revised the challenge again). At this point i already have other assignments that i must focus on and don't really have time to mess around with an extra credit assignment that has already passed. It was more of a curiosity, and i wanted to see what other people cam up with. I never wanted a program written for me. Just different points of view of how to solve the problem

Comment: Substituting the top ten repeated tokens in the string with integers 0-9 you can write the program in less than 750 characters.